# "Reputation gained since your last visit to the reputation tab" is making me not want to view my reputation tab

Tags: feature-request, profile-page

Perhaps I'm childish, but I like the little box on my profile which tells me how much reputation I've gained since last looking at my reputation tab.

[image: Example]

It's pretty and green and fills an otherwise empty expanse. The problem is that it's making me not want to visit my reputation tab as I don't want that green box to disappear.

Instead of *reputation gained since your last visit to the reputation tab*, which doesn't really do anything for me other than make me not want to go there, I think it'd be nicer if it was instead *reputation gained in the last 30 days*. This way it'd never reset (well, you know what I mean), and it'd encourage myself and others to continue to actively participate. This would also work well alongside the chart and *top n% this year* text.

---

After accidentally visiting my Reputation page shortly after originally making this post, over a year later and I've still not visited it again...

[image: 1 year on...]

---

Hello from 2017!

[image: 2 years on...]

Comment: It doesn't necessarily stop me from visiting the reputation tab, but I find the number utterly useless. Since I have no idea how long ago I last visited the tab, the number has no significance to me. Showing the rep gain over the last 30 days would certainly be much more meaningful.

Comment: Hehe! I thought I was the only one!

Comment: I have exactly the opposite inclination, I want to visit the reputation page each time I gain reputation, to get that box to go away!

Comment: Which begs the question... what IS the "reputation tab"? (I'm not quite sure myself.) Oh, there it is.

Comment: I'm just the same! The number on my reputation tab currently is 29.9k :-)

Comment: *siiighhh, show off ... grrmmblll*

Comment: Really? I treat that as a notification and check it immediately, every time it appears, out of curiosity.