# Have to click on triangle to view reputation breakdown

Tags: feature-request, bug, reputation, profile-page

Have a look at [your reputation tab in your profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=reputation&sort=post&StartDate=2015-05-15%2015:47:50Z).

To expand / collapse each day to show / hide the breakdown, you have to click the triangle. However, wherever you hover on the line you get the hand cursor, suggesting you can click.

Please can we be able to click anywhere on the line?

Comment: But.. [I can't click it!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/255996/reputation-gained-since-your-last-visit-to-the-reputation-tab-is-making-me-not) :P (used [this instead](http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/252153/tim?tab=reputation&sort=post&StartDate=2015-05-15%2015:47:50Z) :)

Comment: @Sha not that it solves it :P